# How can I setState of the current index of an array being used in a carousel which autoplays, to be passed into another component as a prop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I am using this npm package for a background carousel. https://github.com/u2ix/react-background-slider
It takes in an array of images from props to autoplay the slideshow in a loop. 
I have another component of Cards being mapped and rendered that needs to take in the current index of the carousels images array in order to change the cards state in sequence of the images. I had this working in a previous carousel but the previous carousel had a built in function for capturing the activeIndex so it was easily passed. The goToSlide function also came with the previous carousel package, so I am trying to rewrite it to continue working with my FeatureCards Component.

```
class HomeLanding extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            images: [
                MockExtension,
                image1,
                image2,
                image3
            ],
            activeIndex: 0
        };
    }

goToSlide = i => {

}

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <HomeCard />
                <CardGroup className="CardWrap">
                    {
                        FeaturesInfo.map((item, index) => {
                            return <FeatureCard key={index} isActive={this.state.activeIndex === index} goToSlide={() => this.goToSlide(index)} icon={require(`../../Assets/FeaturesImages/${item.icon}`)} title={item.title} description={item.description} />
                        })
                    }
                </CardGroup>
                <BackgroundSlider
                    images={this.state.images}
                    duration={8}
                    transition={2}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with this library before but from what i understand, you could capture the index and image url from a callback function props.onChange(). I think you should capture the index and then fast forward the slide show until the index is met then slow the slide show down.

Without further code i cant help but i guess that you are trying to use a package in a way that it wasn't created for.